# Proxy-Arp setup with Keepalived

Tags: arp, keepalived, vrrp, ucarp

I currently am trying to create a setup with N servers where 1 server is the master for a Virtual IP, and the (N-1) servers act as backups, presumably controlled by `keepalived`. However, one issue I see with `keepalived` is that its intention is to bind the Virtual IP address (`1.2.3.4`) to whatever interface I specified (let's call it `eth0`).

What I intend to do, instead, is to create a Proxy-ARP entry on `eth0` for `1.2.3.4`. This way, traffic headed to `1.2.3.4` comes to `eth0`, and since `ip_forwarding` is permitted on my host, routing table entries on the host will forward them to a virtual interface for further processing.

Is this use case supported within `keepalived`? I did get this setup working properly with `ucarp`, but this is mainly due to the fact that `ucarp` has the concept of `vip-up` and `vip-down` scripts, where I can insert custom commands to create Proxy-ARP entries and send a GARP.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want this? As far as I know, it is not supported as VRRP is a protocol that needs to be able to talk between all participating hosts on the same subnet.

If you want to share a virtual IP address between several servers, and you want to attach it to a loopback interface, you should look at anycast routing. Run a routing protocol on your servers and on your routers (e.g. OSPF or BGP), let each server advertise the same IP address and make scripts that stop/start advertising the shared virtual IP address based on whatever you want, e.g. a service stops (e.g. Apache crashed) or the server loses/gains connectivity to a backend database etc.